# Naming a directory to upload image too

Tags: php, forms, file-upload

I have the following code to upload an image, this uploads to the base directory I need it to upload to the directory "uploads"

```
    <form action="index.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="file"><br/>
<input type="hidden" value="main" name="filename"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Upload" name="Submit1">

</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))
{ 


$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$name = $_POST["filename"];

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $name.".".$extension);
echo "Old Image Name = ". $_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br/>";
echo "New Image Name = " . $name.".".$extension;


}


?>
```

I have tried fitting the directory name into the code but not knowlegeable to know where i have gone wrong.

Any help or to point me in the right direction would be great

Comment: `$target` should not be used in either `pathinfo` nor `move_uploaded_file`...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol i have updated my question with the basic code im working from, how would i tell the code the directory that i like to upload in?

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing some parenthesis in your code. Compare your code to [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and then use the following to check the POST'd variables...

```
print_r($_POST); exit;
```

and

```
print_r($_FILES); exit;
```

The file needs to be copied from its temp location to your uploads directory using 'move_uploaded_file' but the path must be correct, check your slashes!

Comment: why are you writing in capslock?

Comment: Why would "missing parentheses" cause a *warning* rather than a *syntax error*?

Comment: i have updated my question with the basic code im working from, how would i tell the code the directory that i like to upload in?

Comment: UPDATE: W3CSchool has a good example of the file upload; https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp, this is the "move" step:

    `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file`

The $target_file variable holds the destination path and file name. Past issues were usually related to this variable or permission to this location.

Answer (score 0):

after trying multiple things i sorted it out,

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))
{ 
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES["file"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$name = $_POST["filename"];
$folder = "uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"uploads/". $name.".".$extension);
echo "Old Image Name = ". $_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br/>";
echo "New Image Name = " . $name.".".$extension; 
}
```